# inline check box ajax modify a number

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a html like this for example:

```
<li><label class="desc"><font color="green">Want to get email ($<span id="price">50</span>/month)</font></label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="subscribe" name="subscribe"> bla bla bla</li>

<li><label class="desc">-$30 subscribe</label>
            <input type="checkbox"  id="custom_test" name="custom_test">Please check this to add your own email</li>
```

Stucture:

[checkbox] subscribe (50$/month)
text bla bla

[another checkbox] offer -30$ to add own emails)

So basically i have a check box to subscribe, with a price for that subscription, and under that i have another check box for "offer" if you check that check box it should edit inline the price in the above subscribe with -30$ if checked and and if not stay the same.

how can i do this with a Ajax or some kind of JQuery/JS function to edit in line depending on the ID of that span with id of the second checkbox ?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkfJF/)

Thanks in advance for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do know that you have absolutely awful non-semantic markup, don't you? Before doing anything sane, you need to make it valid and semantic. But for your current situation, here is the jQuery snippet:

```
var price = document.getElementById('price'),
    origPrice = parseInt(price.innerHTML),
    reducedPrice = parseInt(price.innerHTML) - 30;

$('#custom_test').change(function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.checked) {
        price.innerHTML = reducedPrice;
    } else {
        price.innerHTML = origPrice;
    }
});​
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/kkfJF/32/)

Here how you might want to update your markup:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <label class="desc main">
        Want to get email ($<span id="price">50</span>/month)
        <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="subscribe" name="subscribe">
    </label>
    Some text
</li>
<li>
    <label class="desc offer">
        -$30 subscribe
        <input type="checkbox"  id="custom_test" name="custom_test">
    </label>
    Please check this to add your own email
</li>
</ul>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/3e2E8/)

Comment: It certainly does for me. Are you sure it's not caching in the browser? Try force reload (Shift + reload button)

Comment: @Jimmy I have updated the code to work in Firefox (that I believe you are using). Firefox doesn't support innerText property (only Firefox) so I have updated it with innerHTML (that is more of a workaround). Could you please try now?

Comment: is this still working if i have `onclick=` in my input checkbox?

Comment: why would you need that? Inline javascript as inline CSS is a very bad practice. You should keep JS in .js and styling in .css.

Comment: I don't think this is the case but if you absolutely have to have inline onclick= in HTML, keep in mind that it is fired up before 'onchange' (that is in the javascript snippet above). Just so you know.

Comment: something is not working :( i forget to mention i have: Jquery 1.6.2... and can't update at the moment, could the problem be from this? thanks much

Comment: No @Jimmy, jQuery 1.6.2 should be fine. If it doesn't work then either the HTML you give is wrong/not-complete/whatsoever or you implement javascript wrongly. The block of javscript you see should be wrapped into jQuery(document).ready(… code above …); block

Comment: it still not working :( and i dont get why .... do you think you can create a chat room so we can talk more and faster? thanks much

Comment: Spliter: it still doesn't work, in a simple page is working, but i need it to make it work in a popup form, and it's not working do you have any idea please?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have more than one element with ID 'price' in your HTML. Then the code will not work as expected of course. But this is not the problem of the solution. Do you have any JS errors in your browser's console?

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery this would be like

```
$('#custom_test').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#price").text($('#price').text()*1 - 30);    
    }else{
        $("#price").text($('#price').text()*1 + 30);   
    }
});
```

Checkout the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kkfJF/29/

Hope this helps

Comment: Don't use jQuery where simple javascript is doing just fine.

Comment: @slevon : is this still working if i have `onclick=` in my input checkbox?

Comment: @Jimmy: I don't know exactly what your point is. The markup I provided needs jQuery. If you use jQuery, there is no need to use the onclick="" arrtibute and it's not common sense

Comment: @spliter: As Jimmy tagged his question with jQuery I asumed he likes to use it. Hope you agree that if you use jQuery you should stick to it and it's design pattern.

Comment: no, @slevon, I totally disagree. You use tool that is appropriate for every particular task. And if somebody want to use jQuery, it doesn't mean you should advise bad practices. Sorry, but replacing the simplest pure javascript method with a jQuery "built-on-top" is considered a bad practice, not a "design pattern".

Comment: @slevon the on click is for another thing, but still not working and i don't get why :( i wrapped inside a `.ready` and still not working

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. What does not work? If you want some additional code to be executed you can simply add it to the `.change` function. And remember I recommend the Answer of spliter, too.