# inline check box ajax/jquery change a number in a Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [inline check box ajax modify a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642810/inline-check-box-ajax-modify-a-number)

I have a html like this for example:

```
<li>
    <label class="desc">
        <font color="green">
            Want to get email ($<span id="price">50</span>/month)
        </font>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="subscribe" name="subscribe"> bla bla bla
</li>

<li>
    <label class="desc">-$30 subscribe</label>
    <input type="checkbox"  id="custom_test" name="custom_test">Please check this to add your own email
</li>
```

Stucture:

[checkbox] subscribe (50$/month) text bla bla

[another checkbox] offer -30$ to add own emails)

So basically i have a check box to subscribe, with a price for that subscription, and under that i have another check box for "offer" if you check that check box it should edit inline the price in the above subscribe with -30$ if checked and and if not stay the same.

how can i do this with a Ajax or some kind of JQuery/JS function to edit in line depending on the ID of that span with id of the second checkbox in a **POPUP**?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkfJF/)

Please review also this solutions didn't work:

[slevon soltuion](http://jsfiddle.net/kkfJF/29/)

[spliter solution](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/kkfJF/32/)

**Jquery version:1.6.2**

Thanks in advance for all!

Comment: You're charging people $50 to get email from you?

Comment: it's a dummy text, not a real text.

Comment: I just had a look at the solutions you linked to. They seem to do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @Asad Yes :( this is the annoying part, it's not working for me in the popup at all, see my comment on ur solution please

Comment: There are no "popups" in the JSfiddle you have provided. What are you talking about?

Comment: in the JSfiddle can't make popup, but in the description of question i bold it, that page in jsfiddle is in fact a popup page. and that's my problem is not working there, in a normal page it's working but in that popup not really, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I don't know why anybody would vote `close` on this question as i didn't violate any rules of stackoverflow.com ...

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of your previous questions on the topic. I therefore voted to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: It's not duplicate! this one shows very clear that i want this in a popup as in the prev question was for a simple page ...

Comment: You should edit that information into the previous question then. Feel free to bring this up on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the price in a `data` attribute. That way you can calculate the value to be displayed in the `change` handler of the checkbox:

```
$('#custom_test').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('#price').text($('#price').data('price') - 30);
    }else{
        $('#price').text($('#price').data('price'));
    }
});
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/kkfJF/40/

Comment: That's cool. Never used (or seen used) data attr that way.

Comment: @Asad thanks for your answer, it still not working and i'm getting crazy over this :(( it's a popup and not working, i put it between `$(document).ready(function() { });` still not working

Comment: @TimJoyce I use it for this kind of thing pretty frequently, as a sort of "true value" indicator on an element. Pretty convenient IMO. :)

Comment: @Asad the check box has also `onclick` for anither gray out some inputs function, could this mess up things (that function is working)?

Comment: @Jimmy You should accept the answer provided on the earlier question instead, since it accomplishes the same thing. Thanks for understanding the problem.

Comment: @Asad i accepted both, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#custom_test').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) 
            $('span#price').html('20');
        else
            $('span#price').html('50');
    });
});
```